# Remember sudo password until screen lock possible?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo, lock

I usually use Linux as my standard working system and I learned a lot from actually using it. For this particular question I found no answer yet.

The `sudo` command usually remembers me typing in my password for a given time (usually 15 minutes I guess). Is it possible to extend this time to an undefined length but instead ask for the password again after locking my screen?

I always lock my screen when I leave my computer alone (even for seconds) and would like to not always retype my password when doing something.

I dont want to disable the password check in general. If I let anyone doing anything on my computer they still shouldnt be able to use the `sudo` command without me typing it once first.

Comment: What does your research say?

Comment: An alternative solution would be to keep a su termial open for commands that need sudo-powers and to just make sure that you password lock your screen when leaving.

Comment: My research indicates that basically it would involve running a bash script in the background, that keeps sudo active, sort of a [hack](http://serverfault.com/questions/266039/temporarlly-increasing-sudos-timeout-for-the-duration-of-an-install-script) if you wask me.  Although given that it is possible on [OS X](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10139/how-do-i-increase-sudo-password-remember-timeout) I can't imagine Ubuntu does not have something similar.  So what does your research show is the case?

Comment: I haven't found anything regarding this to be honest. There seems to be no functionality for this but the answer I selected is promising.

Comment: look into your /etc/pam.d/ files, you should be able to set a more desirable timeout/ memory of sudo there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can make your screen-lock mechanism run an extra command on locking, then you can edit `/etc/sudoers` to add a line for your user id, eg `myname`, which says

```
Defaults:myname timestamp_timeout=-1
```

This makes the timeout infinite. To revoke your sudo rights explicitly, run `sudo -k` from your screen-lock.

As usual when editing this file take precautions, eg use `sudo visudo` and ensure you have a root shell ready in some other terminal.

Comment: This sounds like a wonderful idea. Will try it and check back as soon as I was able to. Sounds like this is the solution.